# Firestore: deleting multiple documents attempts to delete the same doc again

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am setting up a function to delete multiple Firestore documents based on a property in the document. It does work, but when it executes, it may attempt to delete the same document twice as (added a console log statement to verify). Here is the method:

```
   async deleteDocuments<T>(collectionName: string, fieldToCheck: string, stringValueToCheck: string) {
      // Get a collection based on the field being checked and then set a property for document ID to 'id'
      this._afs.collection(collectionName)
         .ref.where(fieldToCheck, '==', stringValueToCheck)
         .onSnapshot(async x => {
            if (x) {
               x.forEach(async doc => {
                  try {
                     console.log(`deleting: ${collectionName}/${doc.id}`)
                     await doc.ref.delete();
                  } catch (error) {
                     console.log(error)
                  }
               })
            }
         })
   }
```

It doesn't try repeatedly on all the documents though and that is really confusing. As an example, I had three documents and when I ran this, it iterated through two of the documents twice, and one document one time. I tried it on another set of documents which had a dozen or so and it looked like it had the same result (though I'm not positive about a 1:3 ratio).

Comment: I suggest editing your question to show the **specific details** of a case where it always behaves as you expect.  There should be enough information in your post so that anyone can reproduce it.   If you're saying it happens randomly, that's not really enough useful information to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are subscribing to some query, and of course the result changes as you delete one or several of the elements. I fixed your code so instead of subscriptions you would delete them once.

```
async deleteDocuments<T>(collectionName: string, fieldToCheck: string, stringValueToCheck: string) {document ID to 'id'
      const docs = await this._afs.collection(collectionName)
         .ref.where(fieldToCheck, '==', stringValueToCheck)
         .get();
      docs.forEach(doc => doc.ref.delete());
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, that was it!